# How to write binary data to DataMatrix in ZPLII BASE256

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii, datamatrix

I'm trying to write binary data to a DataMatrix barcode using ZPL. My problem is that the resulting barcode seems to be corrupted.

```
^BXB,3,200,26,26,6,,^FH^FD_45_46_42_13^FS
```

results in

```
0x46 0x47 0x43 0x14
```

when read using libtdmtx and other libraries.

Why is there an offset of +1?
Some decoder libraries say that that code is using TEXT instead BINARY. How do I force BINARY mode?